# Can't find `acmart` package in basicTeX

Tags: tlmgr, acmart

I am getting an error claiming latex can't find the package `acmart` and it is not available in `tlmgr`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  But this isn't even close to enough information for anyone to help you.  What system are you running?  What version?  What have you tried?  What is the exact text of the error?  And so forth.

Comment: Sorry, I actually did solve the problem, I just wanted to post it and the answer here for posterity. The answer does not depend on the specifics of my system, should I append my system information anyway?

Comment: No, no need, as it looks like there's an easy solution to the problem.  But in general, more information is better.

Answer (score 3):

`acmart` is not part of the distribution of `basictex` so it needs to be installed. Furthermore `tlgmr` (texlive's package manager) needs to be configured to know  where to look for packages. Finally, it looks like `tlmgr` does not track down dependencies so they each need to be installed by hand. All this put together is resolved by the following sequence of commands:

```
sudo tlmgr option repository ctan
sudo tlmgr option repository http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet
sudo tlmgr update --all
sudo tlmgr install acmart
sudo tlmgr install iftex
sudo tlmgr install xstring
sudo tlmgr install environ
sudo tlmgr install totpages
sudo tlmgr install trimspaces
sudo tlmgr install manyfoot
sudo tlmgr install ncctools
sudo tlmgr install comment
sudo tlmgr install balance
sudo tlmgr install preprint
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think this actually provides an answer to the question ("Where is `acmart`?"; or, "Why can't `tlmgr` find `acmart`?).